# How to show that node.js has less overhead

Tags: node.js

I'm searching for examples that show how to telnet on node.js app port and show how this has less overhead than telnetting on apache http port.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Define "overhead". Server RAM? Server CPU? Network traffic? What do you actually want to show? "Less RAM" isn't generally too useful, at least when compared to "Able to handle more concurrent users"

Comment: Overhead is kind of vague. Also there might be more overhead for a single request. node.js excels at asynchronous io where a request can be served while another is waiting on io. Isaacs explains this well in this talk http://vimeo.com/slexaxton/txjs-2013-isaac-schlueter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about overhead in HTTP headers, I would recommend you use something like Fiddler as this will tell you exactly that is being sent backwards and forwards for any requests.